# Nothing happens on pressing Menu Item

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I am trying to build an app following a tutorial. I have a "Refresh" button that's supposed to populate a ListView (through and ArrayAdaptor)with an array of data from an API call but when I press the "Refresh" button. The button is supposed to run `updateWeather()` method to load the ListView with some weather data that looks like this (This data appears in my Log actually):

Can someone please help with this. Can't seem to get my head around it.

```
05-10 23:23:23.921: V/FetchWeatherTask(2037): Forecast entry: Sun May 10 - Clouds - 10/8
05-10 23:23:23.921: V/FetchWeatherTask(2037): Forecast entry: Mon May 11 - Clear - 17/5
05-10 23:23:23.921: V/FetchWeatherTask(2037): Forecast entry: Tue May 12 - Rain - 21/8
05-10 23:23:23.921: V/FetchWeatherTask(2037): Forecast entry: Wed May 13 - Rain - 15/10
05-10 23:23:23.921: V/FetchWeatherTask(2037): Forecast entry: Thu May 14 - Rain - 20/15
05-10 23:23:23.922: V/FetchWeatherTask(2037): Forecast entry: Fri May 15 - Rain - 13/11
05-10 23:23:23.922: V/FetchWeatherTask(2037): Forecast entry: Sat May 16 - Rain - 13/8
```

ForecastFragment.java

```
package com.example.siaw.sunshine;

import ...

public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> forecastAdaptor;

    public ForecastFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_refresh){
           updateWeather();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        forecastAdaptor = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, new ArrayList<String>());

        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(forecastAdaptor);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String forecast = forecastAdaptor.getItem(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class)
                        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, forecast);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    private void updateWeather() {
        FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String location = prefs.getString(getString(R.string.pref_location_key),
                getString(R.string.pref_location_default));
        weatherTask.execute(location);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        updateWeather();
    }

    public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {

        private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();

        /* The date/time conversion code is going to be moved outside the asynctask later,
         * so for convenience we're breaking it out into its own method now.
         */
        private String getReadableDateString(long time){
            // Because the API returns a unix timestamp (measured in seconds),
            // it must be converted to milliseconds in order to be converted to valid date.
            SimpleDateFormat shortenedDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd");
            return shortenedDateFormat.format(time);
        }

        /**
         * Prepare the weather high/lows for presentation.
         */
        private String formatHighLows(double high, double low) {
            // For presentation, assume the user doesn't care about tenths of a degree.
            long roundedHigh = Math.round(high);
            long roundedLow = Math.round(low);

            String highLowStr = roundedHigh + "/" + roundedLow;
            return highLowStr;
        }

        /**
         * Take the String representing the complete forecast in JSON Format and
         * pull out the data we need to construct the Strings needed for the wireframes.
         *
         * Fortunately parsing is easy:  constructor takes the JSON string and converts it
         * into an Object hierarchy for us.
         */
        private String[] getWeatherDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr, int numDays)
                throws JSONException {

            // These are the names of the JSON objects that need to be extracted.
            final String OWM_LIST = "list";
            final String OWM_WEATHER = "weather";
            final String OWM_TEMPERATURE = "temp";
            final String OWM_MAX = "max";
            final String OWM_MIN = "min";
            final String OWM_DESCRIPTION = "main";

            JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
            JSONArray weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST);

            // OWM returns daily forecasts based upon the local time of the city that is being
            // asked for, which means that we need to know the GMT offset to translate this data
            // properly.

            // Since this data is also sent in-order and the first day is always the
            // current day, we're going to take advantage of that to get a nice
            // normalized UTC date for all of our weather.

            Time dayTime = new Time();
            dayTime.setToNow();

            // we start at the day returned by local time. Otherwise this is a mess.
            int julianStartDay = Time.getJulianDay(System.currentTimeMillis(), dayTime.gmtoff);

            // now we work exclusively in UTC
            dayTime = new Time();

            String[] resultStrs = new String[numDays];
            for(int i = 0; i < weatherArray.length(); i++) {
                // For now, using the format "Day, description, hi/low"
                String day;
                String description;
                String highAndLow;

                // Get the JSON object representing the day
                JSONObject dayForecast = weatherArray.getJSONObject(i);

                // The date/time is returned as a long.  We need to convert that
                // into something human-readable, since most people won't read "1400356800" as
                // "this saturday".
                long dateTime;
                // Cheating to convert this to UTC time, which is what we want anyhow
                dateTime = dayTime.setJulianDay(julianStartDay+i);
                day = getReadableDateString(dateTime);

                // description is in a child array called "weather", which is 1 element long.
                JSONObject weatherObject = dayForecast.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
                description = weatherObject.getString(OWM_DESCRIPTION);

                // Temperatures are in a child object called "temp".  Try not to name variables
                // "temp" when working with temperature.  It confuses everybody.
                JSONObject temperatureObject = dayForecast.getJSONObject(OWM_TEMPERATURE);
                double high = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MAX);
                double low = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MIN);

                highAndLow = formatHighLows(high, low);
                resultStrs[i] = day + " - " + description + " - " + highAndLow;
            }

            for (String s : resultStrs) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Forecast entry: " + s);
            }
            return resultStrs;

        }
        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... params){
            // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
            // so that they can be closed in the finally block.

            if (params.length == 0){
                return null;
            }

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            //TODO: track and remove.
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
            String forecastJsonStr = null;

            String format = "json";
            String units = "metric";
            int numDays = 7;

            try {
                final String FORECAST_BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
                final String QUERY_PARAM = "q";
                final String FORMAT_PARAM = "mode";
                final String UNITS_PARAM = "units";
                final String DAYS_PARAM = "cnt";

                Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                        .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0])
                        .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format)
                        .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM, units)
                        .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM, Integer.toString(numDays))
                        .build();

                URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());

                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Built URI " + builtUri.toString());

                // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Read the input stream into a String
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    // Nothing to do.
                    return null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                    // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                    // buffer for debugging.
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                    return null;
                }
                forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Forecast String: " + forecastJsonStr);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("ForecastFragment", "Error", e);
                // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attempting
                // to parse it.
                return null;
            } finally{
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e("ForecastFragment", "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }

            try {
                return getWeatherDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr, numDays);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //This will only happen if there was an error getting/parsing the forecast.
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
            if (result != null) {
                forecastAdaptor.clear();
                for (String dayForecastStr : result) {
                    forecastAdaptor.add(dayForecastStr);
                }
                // New data is back from the server.  Hooray!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The data in this ListView is actually not from the API call, the funny thing is I deleted the static String array that's holding THIS data but after cleaning and rebuilding, the static data still appears. I am not sure why this is happening. In the code this data has been removed!

[image]

I want to populate this fake data with the data from the API call with the kind of data that shows in LogCat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the main issue is that you are not calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` after modifying the data set in `onPostExecute()`.  This should be all you need to get it working:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
    if (result != null) {
        forecastAdaptor.clear();
        for (String dayForecastStr : result) {
            forecastAdaptor.add(dayForecastStr);
        }
        // New data is back from the server.  Hooray!
        forecastAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //added
    }
}
```

As an alternative, I usually prefer to do all data manipulation on the underlying `ArrayList` instead of using the methods of `ArrayAdapter`, see below for details:

Create a `ArrayList<String>` as a member variable, which will be your data source for the `ListView`:

```
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> forecastAdaptor;
    private ArrayList<String> data; //added

    //.........
```

Initialize in `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    data = new ArrayList<String>(); //added
}
```

Then, pass in the data source when calling `setAdapter()`:

```
 forecastAdaptor = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.list_item_forecast,
            R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, data);
```

Then, in `onPostExecute()` of your `AsyncTask`, update the data source, then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
    if (result != null) {
        //forecastAdaptor.clear(); //no need for this
        data.clear();  //clear the data source
        for (String dayForecastStr : result) {
            //forecastAdaptor.add(dayForecastStr);
            data.add(dayForecastStr); //update data source
        }
        // New data is back from the server.  Hooray!
        forecastAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //added
    }
}
```

See [documentation for notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged())

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I have cleaned and rebuilt the source code but no change. I am not really sure if Android Studio(AS) is recognizing the changes I have made. It happened before till I reinstalled AS for it to acknowledge some changes I have made. I don't know why. You (or maybe someone) has some tips on this?

Comment: i have to uninstall every time i make a change to code?

Comment: @siaw23 Not normally, no.  But it sounds like something strange is going on, and that might help you narrow it down!

Comment: now i get `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference` after reinstalling. i tried to change `private ArrayList<String> data` to `private ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();` thinking that should fix the problem.

Comment: @siaw23 Ahh yeah, best to initialize it in `onCreate()` I'll update the answer.